# Hover on a button

Tags: jquery, css, button

I'm using jquery to add some button on my web page. I want to add an hover option and change the color of the button. So I use something like :

```
#nameOfTheButton:hover
{
    background-color: #558B47;
}
```

And I get this :

[image]

So the button isn't entirely colored in green but just a little strip at the bottom.

I'm using these links to add jquery :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

What should I do to color the entire button ?

Comment: how is the button created

Comment: inspect and see the button structure and add the specific css for those elements.

Comment: Please create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net of your code and post it to understand it better.

Comment: @Jai I did. I inspected my button and the problem came from a bootstrap file where it assign a css by default. Thanks :)